# How to get servlet path in jsp?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I'm trying to use a dynamic way to call my servlet resources,methods, etc.. in my jsp pages.
Currently i'm using `<form action=/TestServlet/reg` /> how can i get the servlet path or name in my pages without using TestServlet manually !?

Comment: Why would you need that to be dynamic? The servlet is mapped to a well-defined static URL, that doesn't change over time. So there's nothing dynamic here.

Comment: @JBNizet Actually, the root context can be configured at deployment (one common use case is [blue-green deployment](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/BlueGreenDeployment.html)). The JEE specification is highly *dynamic*.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch agreed. I didn't understand that the OP wanted to make the context path dynamic.